# How to rank a column of a Table in Power BI with a condition

Tags: powerbi

I have this table in PowerBI

| Name | Count | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 2 |
| D | 2 | 1 |

How can I Rank the value of `Count` column only if Type is same? i.e. have a rank when Type equals to 1, have a rank when Type is 2?

So that I get

| Name | Count | Type | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| D | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **calculated column**

```
Rank = 
VAR ThisType = 'Table'[Type]
RETURN
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[Type] = ThisType
        ),
        'Table'[Count],
        ,
        ,
        DENSE
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't this solve your problem? What's the issue then?